# how to know bounded type parameter on a class

Tags: java, generics

I declared a class like this:

```
public class TestManagerImpl<T extends IParams> implements TestManager<T> {

  public TestManagerImpl() {}
  ...

}
```

I wanted to know, if it was possible to extract which type from IParams is T when an object is instancied for this class ?
When i try to test on a getClass(), it doesn't give me a Type that implements ParameterizedType.

I'v read that I can't, due to type erasure. [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html). But i'm not sure that it's related to my problem, isn't it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `Class` object to constructor. But I don't know if it is good practice.

Comment: It's a standard way of doing it. See the end of the chapter on Generics in Bloch's Effective Java

Comment: private final Class<T> clazz;

    public TestManagerImpl(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
I wanted to avoid it ( as it's some beans autowired by spring) .

Comment: it's not an anti pattern and often the only way for class to know it's own generic type.

Answer (score 2):

Type erasure is *precisely* the problem here.  You cannot discover at run-time what `T` is because that information is not preserved by the compiler.  The only way to find out is if you actually have an object of type `T` passed into one of your methods (@Nikita suggests one such mechanism, but of course it relies on the cooperation of whoever is using your class).